# JPA EntityManager not throwing Constraint Violation on delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

For my project i have to allow the User to delete some Database entries. But in my case it should fail now, because there a some restrictions in Database. I can't show the Database DDL, because i am not allowed to.

The problem is that the code is not throwing any error, so the outcome is a message which says that the item was deleted. But of course it will fail, because a constraint violation.

So in the moment i will give the User a positive feedback for this action, but it should be a negative. The item is still in Database, this will confuse the User later on, if the item is not deleted. If there is no constraint violation, the entity will be deleted.

My code to remove entities looks like this, T is is defined in extending classes, to not replicate code.

Thanks in advance!

```
public void delete(final T item) throws DAOException {
    EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerFactoryCentral.getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.contains(item) ? item : entityManager.merge(item));
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {
            transaction.rollback();
        } catch (Exception rollbackEx) {
            logDatabaseError(rollbackEx);
        }

        logDatabaseError(ex);
        throw new DAOException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    logTransactionSuccess(item, REMOVED_FROM);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete an User's row directly in the database? Also, put the app in debug mode to see the generated SQL commands.

Comment: Yes, already done that. As is said there is a Constraint violation.

Comment: Can you post the generated SQL commands for entityManager.remove (...)?

Comment: Ok i discovered now, it's not generating any SQL commands for this item.

Comment: I had to overwrite that method, the EntityManager had problems to delete a Object after merging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your remove line with this one:

```
entityManager.remove(entityManager.getReference(item.getClass(), item.getPk()));
```

where PK is your primary key in that entity (not sure it's that simple since you have generics).

That merge IMO doesn't make much sense since you delete the entity.

Comment: Yeah won't be work with generics, i have to overwrite this method by it's extending class. Your Solution works now with that. Thank you !

Comment: @M.Soldin I'm glad it helped you.